# 20W Apple Charging Brick — still safe to use after *mishap*?

Tags: hardware, charging, damage

While removing my charging brick from the power outlet, a metal button slipped from my hand and went between the adapter (not fully removed) and the power socket—which was switched on at that time—resulting in a reasonably terrifying spark and my new 20W Apple Power adapter looking like this:

[image]

I know it's probably hard, if not impossible, to ascertain whether the brick is still safe to use, but I want to ask nevertheless: **should I still use this to charge my iPhone 12**, or trouble my dad to buy me a new one?

PS: The black powdery stuff appears to be from the button

---

UPDATE:

I examined the adapter a bit closer and there seems to be a circular patch of metal exposed on both *arms* which is complementary to the ones I see on the button.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't.  It's more than likely safe, the short was outside the adapter.  But adapters are cheap, phones are not.

Comment: I'm still wondering how that would be possible to do, even intentionally, on a modern plug/socket. The pins should be plastic wrapped at the back, preventing any short whilst the actual terminals are still in contact. Theoretically, if it did short, then as the short is before the 'workings' all that would happen is the fuse/trip would cut the power. In practise, I'd throw it away & put it down to extreme bad luck… or an experiment gone badly wrong. The burn pattern actually hints at an internal short, not external.

Comment: That second photo bothers me. Are you certain that's genuine? I didn't think anyone would still be producing plugs with metal right to the base. The lower half or so of each pin ought to be plastic-wrapped, precisely to prevent this issue from ever happening. See - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xpsO.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those scorch marks are enough to possibly damage the internals. I would seek repair from Apple. They will often cover the cost of repair to analyze the part and ensure you have a safe charging experience.

Using that could be a fire hazard. If you can afford a new one, buy immediately. If you can not afford a replacement, even more important that you don’t use this and risk a fire at home or school or work with a limited budget. Charge your phone from any other source until someone trained to evaluate the part can advise you.

Excellent photos and I’m so happy you didn’t have worse results from that AC arc and short circuit experience.